# How to play mp3 stream using the MediaElement class from WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, mediaelement

I wondering if the MediaElement component (from WPF) is capable of playing and buffering mp3 streams.

I need play mp3 memory stream(not mp3 file) using MediaElement of WPF, if possible would you please tell me how to do it.

thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is functionality has not been implemented in WPF.  There is a workaround quoting from a codeproject

> "Since MediaElement control with
>   Source property from WPF cannot
>   receive byte[] or Stream, we can
>   manipulate it using ASP.NET as a video
>   stream."

[Building a Personal Diary with WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PersonalDiary.aspx)

Alternatively you could embed a plugin such as the [VideoLan DotNet for WinForm & WPF](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) which can stream files, and has very wide codec support.  The downside to this is VideoLAN needs to be installed locally on the machine.

On another note there is a feature request to implement this in WPF.  If you feel obliged, then vote;

[WPF Feature Suggestions - Add stream capability to MediaElement](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/40583-wpf-feature-suggestions/suggestions/490200-add-stream-capability-to-mediaelement)

Answer (score -5):

```
MemoryStream s;
...

MediaElement m = new MediaElement();
m.SetSource(s);
```

Comment: But this class is in System.Windwos.dll that is belong to Silverlight not WPF(in PresentationFramework.dll).
they have the same class name and the Wpf version does not 
support this method.

Comment: It won't work when I reference the same class name(and the same namespace)in my WPF project.

Comment: SetSource is not available in the WPF MediaElement.