# MediaElement in WPF play video from stream?

Tags: c#, wpf, video

I have an element:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="bgvideo" Width="800" Height="600" />
```

and I have a stream video:

```
Stream stream = obj.GetFileStream();
```

I want to use stream object to source of `MediaElement`, but default `MediaElement`  use `source` attribute.

Comment: you can't set a stream directly. Check out this thread for possible workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream

Comment: thanks, your're link recommended use BoxedApp

Comment: You cannot do it with WPF MediaElement. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream

Answer (score 0):

The wonderful Vlc.DotNet library helps with this - more overhead but integrates VLC stream capabilities with WPF to achieve your goal. There are other options as well for most project types.

[Check it out here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vlc.DotNet.Wpf/)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Vlc.Dotnet support for libvlc 4 is not planned [(ref.)](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet). You can use Videolan.LibVLC Libraries from this [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/videolan) library or their [code repository](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-nuget).