# Playing WPF Sound files from resources using MediaElement won't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I've looked up a lot of threads in here, none have helped. I can't seem to play sound files from resources using MediaElement. SoundPlayer works but it's very limited. It doesn't support pause or resume, or anything important.

```
 class Songs
    {
        static MediaPlayer Player = new MediaPlayer();
        public static void PlaySong()
        {
            Player.Open(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Songs/RandomSong.mp3"));
            Player.Play();
        }
    }
```

Something like this doesn't give any errors, but doesn't play the song.

Is it possible to play from resources using MediaElement? If not, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

How about `SoundPlayer`?

Define your audio file(s) as `Resource`

```
var player = new SoundPlayer(Application.GetResourceStream("/YourAssemblyName;component/Songs/RandomSong.mp3").Stream);

player.Play();
```

Comment: SoundPlayer is very limited. It doesn't support Pause or Resume

Comment: Try changing "pack://application:,,,/Songs/RandomSong.mp3" with "/YourAssemblyName;component/Songs/RandomSong.mp3"

Comment: Sadly, doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you changed "YourAssemblyName" with the name of your project?

Comment: Yes, I have changed that. It just gives an invalid url exception

Comment: Try setting the build action to `Embedded Resource` for your audio files. More than probably either your build action is wrong or your `Uri` is wrong.

Comment: I've created a folder inside my Project and I've already put the song as Resource at the build action. Here is how my Uri looks  `Player.Open(new Uri("/MusicProject;component/Songs/RandomSong.mp3"));`

Comment: Sadly it seems like there's no easy way to achieve this. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348897/read-audio-file-to-stream-with-mediaplayer-wpf