# How to create Source for WPF Media Element from byte array using c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, byte, mediaelement, memorystream

I have converted a video to bytes array and stored it in MsSql Database.
Now I fetch it from database and I get the byte array. I want to set this byte array as Source of media element and then show this video in WPF application.

Please suggest a way where I can convert byte array or memory stream to Media Elements Source?

I  will not have permission to write on users machine, so writing a file onto user machine and then setting the source will not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not directly possible. Only the `MediaElement` from Silverlight supports that feature. There are some workarounds. Checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream).