# WP8 MediaElement Source

Tags: windows-phone-8, mp4, mediaelement, ip-camera

I am trying to set a media element to play a video from a http source.  The source is from a ip camera and it just isn't working, and I am not sure why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using FullCam.Resources;

namespace FullCam
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        string sourceURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/display_pic.cgi?cam=1&id=807933130&res=hi&format=mp4&txmode=binary";
        InitializeComponent();

       // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        iniCamBox(camBox_1, sourceURL, "user", "password");
    }

    private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
     {
        // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
        appBarButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
       ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

       // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
       ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AppBarMenuItemText);
        ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
    }

    private void iniCamBox(MediaElement box, string source, string user, string pass)
    {
        Uri mainSource = new Uri(source);

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mainSource);
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

        box.Source = mainSource;
        box.Play();
    }
}
}
```

I have never done this before, so I am not positive I am proceeding correctly.

Comment: HI! Have you try to read your 'sourceUrl' with other player? ( VLC, Windows Media Player, or a browser) and that works ??

Comment: I have used the sourceurl in chrome web browser and it works fine both as jpeg and mp4 source.

Comment: Place `box.Play()` in `_MediaOpened`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to take a look at this tutorial [MSDN Media Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR242926)

Comment: I took a look at the tutorial, but I still don't see why what I have above wouldn't work?

Comment: vidBox is not defined /or at least not in that code you show/

Comment: I placed the control using the visual editor. It is there, just doesn't seem to be playing video from source? The source is working.

Comment: <MediaElement x:Name="vidBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream sounds similar to your problem.