# Video Streaming in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

### Video Streaming in WPF Application

I am developing an WPF application.I need to load encrypted videos stored in local folder.How can I decrypt it and play using streaming mechanism? MediaElement is the control that i am using for loading video. please help me.

Comment: What format are the videos in and what method of encryption is used?  What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using wmv format. Now I am replacing first bytes of videofile stream with some other bytes and saves the original bytes in another location.Before playing video I am just replacing it with original bytes

Comment: But the file remains uncorrupted till video stops. that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to just open the file using a decryption stream, but apparently MediaElement doesn't allow you to [play a stream directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream).

If having the unencrypted file left the user's file system isn't a problem, you could just decrypt the file as one step, then assign the source of the MediaElement to the decrypted file.

If leaving the unencrypted version laying around isn't an option, then you will likely need to investigate another playback component (some are outlined in the [answer I referenced above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream)).