# Convert base64 Video file in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to convert base64 video in Windows Phone,

I have base64 string :

```
string str = "aqtuphnzx+rnmhjqipo";
```

How do I convert?

Thanx!!

Comment: _convert base64 string to video_ Wait..what? o.O

Comment: That is not a base64 string, it will not have a `+` in the center of the string. Also do you really think a entire video can be represented by 19 characters? Are you sure that the string you have is just not part of a URL for a website or something?

Comment: That's better than any compression algorithm I know...

Comment: Well we need more information, for example how was the string encoded? Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-7, ASCII?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain UTF-8..thnx

Comment: You need to be [updating your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24075445/edit), please remove your comments and instead add the **correct** information to the question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ok..I am doing but help me to solve.thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) utility class to `Convert.FromBase64String()` your input to get the raw bytes. You'll probably want to wrap this byte array in a memory stream while you're at it.

```
var str = "aqtuphnzx+rnmhjqipo";
var videoStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
```

Note that your sample `str` is not actually a base64-encoded string as far as I can tell.

Comment: steven,thank you so much..can you help me little more??How do I set source of Media element of that stream??I have to play video using media element.Thanx

Comment: Don't think you can use `MediaElement` for streams. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream

Comment: thank you steven, can you suggest me a good method, Is IsolatedStorage is useful here?

Comment: I've never programmed for WP before, so I'm not familiar with IsolatedStorage files. However, any way to make your video accessible through a URI (that includes file paths) will suffice. Can you save the video to IsolatedStorage and then get its file path?

Comment: steven, I am saving video in isolated storage, but next what to do that I do not know?thank you