# How to authenticate with MediaElement in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am having a WPF-MVVM desktop application. I want to play a media file in this application. 
The media file is stored at some remote server (actually hosted on IIS). It requires credentials to access it. I am using MediaElement to play the audio file.

The problem is how to specify the credentials with mediaElement?

One workaround is using HttpWebRequest & download the file in some temp folder. Onces downloaded then I can play the local file. But I don't want to create any file locally. Is there any way I can specify the Stream as input to MediaElement.

Atul Sureka

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117589/using-mediaelement-to-play-video-from-stream) related to stream input to media element

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use the syntax **username:password@host** for setting the source.

If not, please provide further information how you are trying to do it and what kind of error you get..

While reflecting my answer, I just found this [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), saying that my answer might be deprecated.

If you are not successful, you might have a look at the link.